# What SSD hard drive is compatible with an HP Compaq 2540p?

Tags: laptop, ssd, compatibility

I have read [this thread](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Hardware-Upgrades-Replacements/HP-EliteBook-2540p-replace-HD-for-SSD/td-p/3049477) but I'm not sure what to look out for and what will cause incompatibility when purchasing an SSD hard drive for this laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me as if this computer supports **1.8"** drives at the SATAII standard.

You will be unable to put in any drives in of a different **size** (2.5", 3.5", 1.2")

While the laptop supports the **SATAII standard**, the SATA standards are forward and backwards compatible so you can put in any SATA drive. You just will be limited to operating at the lowest standard. (If you have a SATAIII drive it will operate at SATAII speeds).

Its seems that this computer also has a option to replace the CD drive with a [hard drive carrier](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FO4XE0U) that supports 2.5" drives. I'm not sure at what SATA standard.

Depending on your needs something like [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA0AJ1GB4305) seems suitable though with this particular drive you will be limited to SATAII speeds.